# How I can export complete scene from blender to json file to use it with three. Js

Tags: three.js

I can export single object to json file..but most free models which I downloaded it from the internet consist itself from multi objects in the scene .. so I need to download the scene 
Ex : the building model consist of 
Door object - window object..ect

Comment: Why not joint all separate objects into one?

Answer (score 1):

The Blender exporter might still support this, but you'd need to switch from THREE.ObjectLoader to THREE.JSONLoader to import your model into three.js. I'm not sure how well-supported that is overall.

The other option, possibly more reliable, would be to use another of Blender's export formats that three.js also supports. I'd suggest trying FBX and glTF ([addon](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/)) to get started. These work with THREE.FBXLoader and THREE.GLTFLoader respectively.